# Data not being read properly reading txt file

Tags: c

So I have a file format that designates the first line of the file to be the number of students total in the file and the next lines are the students with their information(Student ID, Grade, GPA). Formatted like this:

```
30
1320 A 3.9
1200 B 3.3
1250 F 0.0
```

When I am reading in the data into arrays I am not getting the correct info and I'm not sure if its because of how I'm directly reading it in my fscanf or I'm not skipping to the next line. But all thats being stored is random basically random data from memory.

```
void file_sort(char *infile, char *outfile)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(infile, "r");
    int num;
    fscanf(fp, "%d%[^\n]", &num);
    
    int *student_id;
    student_id = (int*) malloc (num * sizeof(int));
    char *grade;
    grade = (char*) malloc (num * sizeof(char));
    double *gpa;
    gpa = (double*) malloc (num * sizeof(double));

    printf("\n%d", num);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d, %c %f%[^\n]", &student_id[i], &grade[i], &gpa[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: To scan a `double`, use `%lf`. And remove the comma after `%d`. There is no comma in the input you've shown.

Comment: I see the first argument to ```fopen``` is infile implying somewhere you stored in the name of the file in a character array called ```infile``` yet I don't see where you do that. Did you forget to do that, or is that just not visible here?

Comment: Enable all waring to catch problems quickly like in `fscanf(fp, "%d%[^\n]", &num);`.  It is faster and more efficient than posting on SO - more productive for you.

Comment: You have two conversion specifications in `fscanf(fp, "%d%[^\n]", &num);` and you only supply one variable; that is not going to lead to happiness.  The number must be followed by something other than a newline (because you used a negated scan set).  Did you mean `"%d%*[\n]"` (a number followed by a newline, but suppressing the assignment for the newline)? That's more nearly sensible, though you'll never know if there was a newline after the number.  You should check that all your `fscanf()` calls succeed. You have `printf("\n%d", num);` — newlines go at the end of the line, not the beginning.

Comment: You should always check that `fopen()` succeeded, though most often your program will crash if it fails and you don't check it.  But it is not good to rely on that — it is undefined behaviour and that can lead to problems.  You should also check that your memory allocations succeeded.  While they're unlikely to fail in small programs like this, it is not safe not to check.

Comment: Have you learned about structures yet?  If you've learned about them, you should be creating and using one.  If you've not yet learned about them, you're excused for not using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question my issue was in worrying about going to the next line while reading the file I created my own problem by include the

```
"%[^\n]"
```

This code below functions properly for anyone coming back to this problem.

```
void file_sort(char *infile, char *outfile)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(infile, "r");
    int num;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);
    printf("\n%d", num);
    int *student_id;
    student_id = (int*) malloc (num * sizeof(int));
    char *grade;
    grade = (char*) malloc (num * sizeof(char));
    double *gpa;
    gpa = (double*) malloc (num * sizeof(double));

    printf("\n%d", num);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d %c %lf", &student_id[i], &grade[i], &gpa[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you're worried about garbage at the end of the lines, the best thing to do is read the entire line with `fgets` and then extract the values you want with `sscanf`. And be sure to check the return value from `sscanf`. In your code, you expect 3 values on each line, so the return value from `sscanf` should be 3. If it's anything other than 3, the code needs to do something about that (like set the missing values to some default, or print and error message and exit).

Comment: @user3386109 Are there any good threads on this? If you don't wanna put in the effort totally understand but I am open to learning.

Comment: There probably are. I would search for `[c] fgets sscanf`

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to give the filename, and then for reading the GPA (double) value you need to use `%lf`, also there is an extra ',' after the `%d`. The following code fixed all these bugs. Hopes it help

```
FILE *fp; 
fp = fopen('YOUR FILE NAME', "r");
int num;
fscanf(fp, "%d%[^\n]", &num);
printf("\n%d", num);
int *student_id;
student_id = (int*) malloc (num * sizeof(int));
char *grade;
grade = (char*) malloc (num * sizeof(char));
double *gpa;
gpa = (double*) malloc (num * sizeof(double));

printf("\n%d", num);

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%d %c %lf%[^\n]", &student_id[i], &grade[i], &gpa[i]);
}
```

Comment: Having N variables of size M is not really that great. It's better to have M instances of a struct with N properties.

Comment: ASLAN  Try compiling `fscanf(fp, "%d%[^\n]", &num);`.